# dojo: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Tags: javascript, dojo

Here is my define's factory function:

```
declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        widgetsInTemplate: true,
        templateString: FiltersTemplate,
        baseClass: 'gis_FiltersDijit',
        i18n: i18n,
        postCreate: function () {
            var pins = ['12-82-080', '04-52-080', '04-77-080'];
            for (p = 0; p < pins.length; p++) {
                var curBox = new CheckBox({
                    value: pins[p]
                });
                domConstruct.place(curBox, 'projPinFilter', 'last');
            }             
        }
```

CheckBox is `'dijit/form/CheckBox'`

why am I getting this error? I am using `dojo/domReady!`.

Here is the relevant html:

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DropDownButton">
                        <span>Proj. PIN</span>
                        <div id="projPinFilter"></div>
                    </button>
```

As you can see, I am trying to simulate populating a dropdown checkbox list with server values.

All advice is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the 1 arguments of `domConstruct.place` is expected to be a domNode. So `curBox.domNode`

I would rather use placeAt:
`curBox.placeAt('projPinFilter')`

Note: `'last'` is default.

If this doesn't help, try to add `console.log(dom.byId('projPinFilter'))`
It should output the domNode you want to append to. If not, then dom is not yet ready (but it is unlikely because you are using `dojo/domReady!`